# Store an array to an array key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to store an array ($temp) into the $data array, where key is prices.

`$data['prices'] = $temp;`

However, PHP converts the array into string instead and is throwing me and error.
Notice: Array to string conversion

Is $data = array('prices' => $temp); the only solution?

> edit:
>   I found my mistake. Yes, $data was used previously as a string that's why PHP is converting the input into string.
>   Problem 2, doing a print_r on $data['prices'] = $xml->result->Prices->Price, shows only 1 set of array. But I am able to retrive 2 sets of result by doing a foreach loop on $data['prices']. Why is that so?

<strike>Content of $temp http://pastebin.com/ZrmnKUPB</strike>

Let me be more clear..
The full xml object I'm trying to extract information from: http://pastebin.com/AuMJiyrw
I'm only interested in the price array (Price_strCode and Price_strDescription) and store them in $data['prices']. End result something like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => (
        [Price_strCode] => 0001
        [Price_strDescription] => Gold
    )
    [1] => (
        [Price_strCode] => 0002
        [Price_strDescription] => Silver
    )
)
```

Comment: What line is giving you array-to-string-conversion?  What are the contents of data and temp?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are doing some other array to string conversion elsewhere, the array is actually being stored as another array.

`$data['prices']` will be an array, which can be accessed as `$data['prices']['key']`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, I have been doing this always and it works fine. You must be doing something else somewhere which is causing your array to convert to strong. share your code here